# Sort argv in a certain order

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

I am trying to sort all parameter argv in alphabetical order but I don't understand why my code don't work when I put 3 parameter or more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(int argc, char argv[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    swap(argc, argv);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void swap(int argc, char argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    char temp;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < argc; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(*(argv + j), *(argv + j + 1)) > 0)
            {
                temp = *(argv + j);
                *(argv + j) = *(argv + j + 1);
                *(argv + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler should nag about `swap(argc, argv);` because `char**` is not compatible with `char[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refined your code to effectively sort the `argv[]` array;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(int argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    swap(argc, argv);

    int n;
    for (n = 1; n < argc; n++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[n]);
    }
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void swap(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < (argc - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[j], argv[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                temp = argv[j];
                argv[j] = argv[j + 1];
                argv[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't give code only answers. Good answers explain what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: @user694733 are you tracking me or something?

Comment: No, I went through questions I have visited in the past few days.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to `swap` an array of char.

So when you are comparing the elements of `argv` into `swap` function you are comparing char not string (array of char).

So you shouldn't call the strcmp for comparing char. (strcmp can't find the '\0' symbol and so raise an error).

You can compare char with the '>' operator.

```
 if (*(argv + j) > *(argv + j + 1 ))
```

EDIT:

If you want use string. You should study about rappresentation in memory in C.

[image: C memory rappresentation]

So your error occour 'cause (argv + j) isn't the j-string.

### Please study about it.